# AdMob testing with GADRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

I'm just trying to test my app with adMob but the best practices section says to use the testing version when testing.

This is the code they supply:

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"MY_SIMULATOR_IDENTIFIER",
                          @"MY_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER",
                          nil];
```

For the simulator identifier what do I put? Do I put an array object for every simulator I'm testing on (i.e. 3.5 inch, 4 inch, iPad etc?) and if so, do I just spell it the exact same way it is spelled  ? (i.e. "iPhone Retina (3.5 inch)") and for the device identifier to I simply put the same identifier I used to sign up my devices on my developer profile?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just leave it as is? Right click MY_SIMULATOR_IDENTIFIER and MY_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER and see if they have a definition when you click jump to definition.

Comment: No they have no definition

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years later... This comment is being output in the console while using the simulator:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
```